# Error displayed while executing a jasper file: "Category series name is null"

Tags: charts, jasper-reports, jaspersoft-studio

I have tried to generate sub report as per the demo available in jasper soft page. but while executing the report i could see the error message saying: "Error displayed while executing a jasper file: "Category series name is null". here I have added screenshot of error and report configuration UI

[image]

[image]

Comment: Steps that i have followed are available at: [this link](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/creating-charts-and-subreports-jaspersoft-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I got same error with my own report. I installed the new version 6.0.4 and now it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by creating a new dataset for my chart and using it instead of selecting Main Dataset.